# iOS [Objective-C / Swift] - 3D reconstruction from cross-section images

Tags: objective-c, swift, metal, 3d-rendering

Just wondering if anyone knows the best way to or if it is even possible or impossible to re-construct 3D rendered object from multiple 2D cross section images.  The images are all organized cross sections around 500 slices.

Are there any Metal APIs to accomplish this? or is there any library that I can use to do this?

Or should Unity engine be able to do this?

Any idea, or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you specifically need this done in Objective-C? It'd be relatively easy to do using something like [ImageJ](https://imagej.net/Welcome), but trying to it in an iOS app is likely to require a lot of work.

Comment: @AllanPoole, thanks for your reply.  Yes, that is exactly what I wanted to do in iOS.  Just curious if what ImageJ provides is doable in iOS.

Comment: Volume rendering is a common method of visualising such datasets, there's a relevant paper [here](http://hpc.uni-due.de/publications/2015/Schiewe_2015_SOTA.pdf). The ImageVis3D app mentioned in this paper has been recently updated, I'm unsure if they make this available as a library.

Comment: @lock Thanks! That could be exactly what I was looking for.  Just contacting them to see the build instructions or documentations for mobile.  Appreciated your help.